# Expected Waiting Time

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Interesting question our professor raised at lecture today, trying to figure out how to solve it. Goes as follows:

"An astronomer goes out at night taking pictures of clusters of comets. Every 5 minutes, a group of comets streaks through the sky, ranging from size 1 to 19, equally likely. The astronomer will not go back to bed until he gets a picture of at most 5 comets. How long can he expect to wait?"

$$
P(x) = 1/19, 1 \leq x \leq 19
$$

And 0 otherwise.

I'm not sure to go where to go with this though.

Some thoughts I've had: The time it would take for you to take a picture of any given comet could be the integration of this entire function from 1 to 19, divided by the total time. So, finding any comet, you the probability would be just 5 divided by 1, which is 5. I'm also thinking that if you wanted to get a picture of a size 19 comet cluster, you would have to wait $5*19 = 95$ minutes. So, I'm thinking that one way of picturing it might be doing it would be to view it as $5 * \frac15 * 19$, or 19 minutes, as the expected wait time. Is my logic correct, or is there a different way of going about this problem?

Comment: Should be: "will not go back to bed until he gets a picture of **at least** $5$ comets".

Comment: @barak manos - Professor's exact words were at most, but he might have misspoken to at least.

Comment: Well what does the astronomer do if he or she sees $6$ comets? Never go back to bed for the rest of his life???

Comment: @barak manos That's a good point, but just to be safe, I thought it best to stick with my professor's exact words, in case there was something else I was missing. What do you think of my logic though in regards to the waiting time?

Comment: @barak manos I was also wondering, the astronomer can just take a picture with $0$ comets (by blocking his/her camera) and go to bed immediately if it is ***at most***. :D

Answer (score 0):

The probability that at least 5 comets have been seen in the first 5 minute period is $$P(T=5) = \tfrac {15}{19}$$

For periods $T=10$ to $25$, use the Law of Total Probability, partitioning on the event of seeing only  1,2,3, or 4 comets in the previous period and then seeing at least 4,3,2, or 1 comet respectively during the period.

The probability that at least 5 comets have been seen in *during* the second 5 minutes: $$\mathbb P(T= 10) = \tfrac 1 {19}(\tfrac {16}{19}+\tfrac {17}{19}+\tfrac {18}{19}+1)$$

The probability that at least 5 comets have been seen in *during* the third 5 minutes: $$\mathbb P(T= 15) = (\tfrac 1 {19})^2(0+\tfrac {17}{19}+2\cdot\tfrac {18}{19}+3\cdot 1)$$

The probability that at least 5 comets have been seen in *during* the fourth 5 minutes: $$\mathbb P(T= 20) = (\tfrac 1 {19})^3(0+0+\tfrac {18}{19}+3\cdot 1)$$

The probability that the fifth comet is seen *during* the fifth 5 minutes: $$\mathbb P(T= 25) = (\tfrac 1 {19})^4$$

Now use these to find: $\mathbb E(T)$

Comment: I think you should replace $T=1,2,3,4,5$ with $T=5,10,15,20,25$.

Comment: Hmm... Fair enough.  @barakmanos